# How add page numbers. Use html2pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, html2pdf, pagination

I need add paginate but still can not find normal manual. Variant what show internet does not work.

```
 $("#create_pdf").click(function () {
            $('button').hide();
            var element = document.getElementById('element');
            html2pdf(element, {
                margin: 1,
                filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                image: { type: 'png', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 2, logging: true, dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'landscape' }
            });

            $('button').show();
        });
```

Comment: Please choose the answer.

Answer (score 7):

After generating the pdf, you can call a function to write the page numbers. Similar to this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var opt = {
    margin: 1,
    filename: 'myfile.pdf',
    image: {
        type: 'png',
        quality: 0.98
    },
    html2canvas: {
        scale: 2,
        logging: true,
        dpi: 192,
        letterRendering: true
    },
    jsPDF: {
        unit: 'mm',
        format: 'a4',
        orientation: 'landscape'
    }
};
html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function(pdf) {
    var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        pdf.setPage(i);
        pdf.setFontSize(10);
        pdf.setTextColor(100);
        pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, (pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 2.3), (pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 0.8));
    }
}).save();
```